# how to hide other img and show correct?

Tags: html, css

Can you please show me how a first span hover can show the img number 1 and other span hover show me pic number 2 and hide the first one? 
My code looks like this ::

```
<div class="overlays">
        <a href="#" class="overlays-a clearfix">
            <img class="overlays-img" src="./pic/1.jpg">
            <img class="overlays-img hidden" src="./pic/2.jpg">
            <img class="overlays-img hidden" src="./pic/3.jpg">
            <img class="overlays-img hidden" src="./pic/4.jpg">
            <img class="overlays-img hidden" src="./pic/5.jpg">
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
            <span>4</span>
            <span class="last-span">5</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

[In this image u can see how that looks :/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdWfl.png)

Comment: What issue are you having with creating this logic?

Comment: Where is the JS? I see only HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If the classes `overlays-img1` and  `overlays-img2` are set to `display: none;` in css style, you can use jquery `.hover()` method and do something like,

```
<div class="overlays">
    <a href="#" class="overlays-a clearfix">
        <img class="overlays-img1" src="./pic/1.jpg">
        <img class="overlays-img2" src="./pic/2.jpg">
        <span class="span1">1</span>
        <span class="span2">2</span>
        <span class="last-span">3</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Implementation of  `.hover()` method

```
       jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $(".span1").hover(function(){
       $(".overlays-img1").css("display", "block");
         });

       $(".span2").hover(function(){
       $(".overlays-img1").css("display", "none");
       $(".overlays-img2").css("display", "block");
        });
        });
```

Or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(".span1").hover(function(){
$(".overlays-img1").fadeIn;
 });

 $(".span2").hover(function(){
  $(".overlays-img1").fadeOut;
  $(".overlays-img2").fadeIn;
  });
   });
```

Or

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(".span1").hover(function(){
$(".overlays-img1").show;
 });

 $(".span2").hover(function(){
$(".overlays-img1").hide;
$(".overlays-img2").show;
 });
 });
```

I'm on mobile. Let me know if my snippets are  malfunctioning because of any typo.